# Changing connection string in pgagent

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgagent

Is there a way to change the connection string in pgagent?
I tried to check through server properties but it is not editable

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the pgAgent configuration file, which is typically located at postgresql.conf or pgagent.conf depending on your setup.

Go to the configuration file and search the section that defines the connection string for pgAgent. This should be in the [pgAgent] section of the configuration file. After your modifications restart the pgAgent service to apply the changes. This can be done using the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo systemctl restart pgagent.service
```